# Select minimum date and associated fields in one select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'd like to select the minimum ProcessStepTwoDtTm and the associated ProcessStepTwoStaffId, but want to know if it is possible to do this in a single select statement? I'm using sql server 2014.

Dataset

```
Id  ProcessStepOneDtTm  ProcessStepTwoStaffId    ProcessStepTwoDtTm
1   2/2/2019            615                      4/2/2019  
2   2/2/2019            232                      5/2/2019
```

Desired output

```
Id  ProcessStepOneDtTm  ProcessStepTwoStaffId    ProcessStepTwoDtTm
1   2/2/2019            615                      4/2/2019
```

At the moment I have:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT Id
       , ProcessStepOneDtTm
       , StaffId
       , ProcessStepTwoDtTm
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProcessStepOneDtTm ORDER BY 
           ProcessStepTwoDtTm) as RowNum
) 
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Is there a way to do this in a single select statement?

Comment: Why do you need to do it in a single `SELECT`? What does that gain you?

Comment: Readability and with that maintainability. I've inherited a stored procedure that is putting together an accumulating snapshot where each milestone in a process is a timestamp. There are about 30 of them and the code is already 1100 lines.

Comment: I don’t think any alternatives are any more readable or maintainable, never mind equivalent in performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `top with ties`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES  . . .           
FROM ?
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProcessStepOneDtTm ORDER BY ProcessStepTwoDtTm)
```

I think the performance for this is a bit worse than in your case.  For the best performance, a correlated subquery often works best:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.ProcessStepTwoDtTm = (select min(t2.ProcessStepTwoDtTm)
                              from t t2
                              where t2.ProcessStepOneDtTm = t.ProcessStepOneDtTm
                             );
```

For performance, you need an index on `(ProcessStepOneDtTm, ProcessStepTwoDtTm)`.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use below single line query

```
select Id, min(ProcessStepOneDtTm), StaffId, min(ProcessStepTwoDtTm) group by ID, StaffId
```